# ESS with many short, parallel chains

Tags: sample-size, markov-chain-montecarlo, acf-pacf

I have a curious problem I would like to share and ask for references and advice about.

I am working on a MCMC problem and I realized that I have big economies of scale when I am drawing many chains at the same time. That is, the cost per iteration of updating 100 chains 1 time is much lower than the cost of updating 1 chain 100 times.
Moreover, I have some evidence that my chains have scant auto-correlation, if any.

Knowing those to elements, I would like to go for the following strategy: instead of updating one chain a couple hundred times, I would like to update a hundred chains a couple times. Even if I have some confidence on the fact that I get a low auto-correlation in my samples, I would like to check for some measure of the quality of the integration. [Effective sample size](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/reference-manual/effective-sample-size-section.html) would be great.

However, the usual formula using auto-correlation with infinite times is not applicable here, because it relies on one chain, with many iterations. I have it the other way around.
My first call is to compute a pooled auto-correlation using all chains, and then plug it in the ESS formula. The mean $\mu$  of the interest parameter $x$ would be

$$\hat \mu = \Sigma _{i=1}^{number ~chains}\Sigma _{j~=~burn~in}^{number ~iterations} x_i^j/((number ~iterations - burn~in)*(number~chains)) ,$$
x_i^j being here the $j^{th}$ iteration of the $i^{th}$ chain. Then, we get the auto-covariance
$$\hat\sigma^2(\delta) = \Sigma _{i=1}^{number ~chains}\Sigma _{j~=~burn~in}^{number ~iterations ~-~ \delta} (x_i^j-\hat \mu)(x_i^{j+\delta}-\hat \mu)/((number ~iterations - burn~in)*(number~chains)),$$
$\delta$ being the lag. The pooled auto-correlation is then obtained as
$$acf(\delta) = \hat\sigma^2(\delta)/\hat\sigma^2(0).$$

For now, I am just plugging that estimation of the auto-correlation into the ESS formula.
I am not sure that I am right though, I think an ESS formula with a finite-dimension correlation matrix instead of an infinite acf would be better.

Anyone with comments, insight, references ?

Comment: It is hard to believe that, within a few iterations, the Markov chain is gaining enough ergodicity to be free of the starting distribution (neither discussed nor mentioned in the question).

Comment: Hello @Xi'an ! Thank you as usual for your comments. When I put ludicrous starting values, the chains take half a dozen iterations, then seem to start mixing around the true parameters. I confess that I prefer to cut corners and start with null parameters, because it takes no time to reach the same mixing region. I did such things as qqplots between the first and last iterations. I obtained perfect straight lines, while I would have obtained twisted stuff if the first iterations were still bound to the starting values.